# How can I subscribe an alarm to a notification or SNS topic using CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I know how to create an alarm using AWS CDK but I don't know how to add a notification to that alarm. How do  I do that?

This is my code for the alarm:

```js
/**
 * Alarm for CPU above 75%
 */
const metric = cluster.metricCPUUtilization();
new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, `CPU above 75% alarm` , {
  metric: metric,
  threshold: 75,
  evaluationPeriods: 3,
  datapointsToAlarm: 2,
});
```

This is what it looks like in the console:

[image: Alarm notification in console]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you need is an SNS topic and a subscription.

First import the required packages:

```
import * as sns from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns";
import * as subscriptions from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions";
```

Then create a topic with an email subscription:

```
const topic = new sns.Topic(scope, 'Alarm topic', {
  displayName: envSpecificName(props.displayName)
});

topic.addSubscription(
  new subscriptions.EmailSubscription(email)
)
```

Finally register the topic as an alarm action:

```
import * as actions from "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch-actions";

...


const metric = cluster.metricCPUUtilization();
const alarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, `CPU above 75% alarm` , {
  metric: metric,
});

alarm.addAlarmAction(new actions.SnsAction(topic));
```

You can find [more examples in documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudwatch-readme.html#alarm-actions)